# Simple custom event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn jquery custom events.

I need to fire a simple event on page load.

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv"> my div</div>
```

I need to call my own event to fire an alert

```
$("#mydiv").custom();
```

i tried the below code.

```
function customfun()
    {
        $("#mydiv").trigger("custom");
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#mydiv").bind(customfun, function () {
            alert('Banana!!!');
        });

    });
```

Comment: bind() expects parameter 1 to be a string or an object, not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call custom events as jquery functions you need, well, define such a function via `$.fn`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //define the event
    $(document).on('custom', function() { 
      alert('Custom event!');
    });

    //define the function to trigger the event (notice "the jquery way" of returning "this" to support chaining)
    $.fn.custom = function(){
        this.trigger("custom");
        return this;
    };

    //trigger the event when clicked on the div
    $("#mydiv").on("click", function() {
        $(this).custom();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind to the same event name -- "custom" -- as the one you triggered.  Like this:

```
$("#mydiv").on("custom", function () { ...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WWmRq/1/)

Comment: `.on()` is next `.bind()`  .. :) :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i have seen in some code samples, people use $("#mydiv").customevent(); other than the built in clickevnts..etc. so how can i call that kind of event?

Answer (score 0):

you can call it by doing so:

```
$.fn.mycustom = function(){
     return this;
};

$("div").mycustom();
```